# Remove overlaping input icon by text in IE

Tags: html, css

Screenshot with example:

[image]

Styles:

```
padding-left: 40px;
background: url(../images/ico_03.png) no-repeat 11px 12px #f9f8f6;
```

**Problem:**

I expect that text will not overlap the icon, like it works in normal browsers :)

Comment: have you tried `overflow:hidden` ?

Comment: Could you show some of your markup and more of your css? If that left padding is on the input it should technically already work...

Comment: that styles is on input, everything works everywhere except of IE

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you try it like this:

Markup:

```
<div class="input"> 
    <div class="input-icon">&nbsp;</div>
    <input type="text" />
</div>
```

CSS:

```
div.input{
   position:relative;
}

div.input-icon{
   left: 40px;
   background: url(../images/ico_03.png) no-repeat 11px 12px #f9f8f6;
   position:absolute;
   z-index:2;
   top:0;
}

div.input input{
   padding-left:50px;
   position:relative;
   z-index:1;
}
```